# Rundeck and Sonatype Nexus integratios

Tags: nexus, sonatype, rundeck

the situation is next:

we have few repositories in local Sonatype Nexus OSS for two env, it is a "site" and "hosted repositories".
Jenkins uploads there builds, currently it is a zip files with *.bin inside, In particular Nexus repo I see list of files, like:

```
*_$BUILD_1.zip
*_$BUILD_2.zip
...
*_$BUILD_n.zip
```

I want to have Rundeck job to chose appropriate version from appropriate repo to deploy, I set up [nexus-rundeck-plugin](https://github.com/rundeck/nexus-rundeck-plugin) in nexus, and [nexus-step-plugins](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/nexus-step-plugins) in Rundeck, I thought, evrth will be ok, but rundeck-nexus steps require things like "Group", "Artifact", "Version", "Packaging", "Classifer", and I do not have these parameters for my *.zip files in local Nexus repo, do you have any suggestion how can I integrate this things?

Comment: found nothing, nexus api does not work as I expected
I have 2 repos, it accessible from browser via next links:
http://172.20.22.77/content/sites/qwerty_backend_dev/
http://172.20.22.77/content/sites/qwerty_backend_qa/

each repo contain few zip files
from Rundeck, I want chose env as Options
and also, in Options section, I would like to chose version of zip file for deploy from URL repo:
http://172.20.22.77/content/sites/qwerty_backend_${option.backend_ver}/
like in this video https://youtu.be/eHaEEBEMRA8?t=2391

Comment: but ULR does not work in Option, there should be json, I did not succeeded with nexus API, could somebody help?

Comment: guys, is there any way to get content of Nexus repository, in json format? using nexus api or nexus-rundeck plugin?

Comment: There are some things I don't understand. Maybe you can edit your question to clarify them: What kind of repository are having in Nexus and what is the language you program in? Usually, Nexus is used to store artifacts produced by Java, but other things are possible. These jar-Files are stored according to the coordinates you mentioned, like groupId, artifactId etc.

Comment: that is actually the biggest problem, tha I have no such things like groupId, artifactId etc

I am not a developer, but devops,

application written on Java, and built by sbt - simple build tool.
I have no idea how to fixed this. I think I should configure SBT to publish project in a Nexus, and groupId artifactId will come automatically ?
currently my repos type - site, should be maven1/maven2 ?

Thanx for patience!

Comment: Did you have a look at https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/sbt.html ?

Comment: Tried it, and it did not help me, I am not a programmer, and do not have a clear vision what is a  artifactis and groupid,

Comment: In a Maven repository, files are not requested or ordered by paths, but by a combination of groupId, artifactId, packaging, classifier and version. If you build with Maven (which is the standard way for Java projects), these are specified by the developer in their pom.xml. I don't know where these values are set in sbt, probably the developer has to set them somewhere in a configuration file.

Comment: @OrestStetsiak Can you share a sample output of what you receive when you visit URL 172.20.22.77/content/sites/qwerty_backend_dev 172.20.22.77/content/sites/qwerty_backend_qa?
I have a working implementation using maven repositories

Comment: @ Gautam Jose 

it returns me a list of files, in html format, and it does not work for rundeck remote url. I workarauded it by creating php script, which returns the same info, but in json, and it works with rundeck as well

Comment: I wondered in 2 things:


1) why nexus-rundeck plugin asks for such things, as groupId, artifactId etc.


2) why there is no ability to get lists of files in particular repo, using nexus api, but without things like groupId, artifactId etc. in url